# Why is my use of exception capturing not good?

Tags: python

```
def parse_input(json_str):
    json_dict = {'input': []}
    try:
        json_dict = json.loads(json_str)
        if 'input' in json_dict:
            json_dict['input'] = json.loads(json_dict['input'])
    except JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f'Invalid json str format: {json_str} {e}')
    except TypeError as e:
        print(f'json_str is not a string: {json_str} {e}')

    return json_dict
```

This function is to parse json string and ALWAYS produce a valid dict object, even if an exception occurs. However, when I process a batch of json strings, it still fails on one of the json strings, and the error is below:

```
json_str is not a string: null argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kafka_consumer.py", line 76, in <module>
    fetch_data(sys.argv[1])
  File "kafka_consumer.py", line 55, in fetch_data
    for input in json_dict['input']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The code produced the error above:

```
        json_dict = parse_input(data)
        for input in json_dict['input']:
            unix_time = input['time']
            ...
```

So the question is, why doesn't the parse_input() produce a valid dict when the exception occurs? Is my way of using the exception capturing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `data` when this happens?

Comment: The error message doesn't show what the data is, but an empty dict should still be returned, right?

Comment: If the exception happens on the second `json.loads()`, you'll return a dictionary where the `input` element isn't a list.

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam Why do you think that? There's no `return` in the `except` blocks.

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam when an exception occurs, I thought it executes the print() statements under the 'except' but don't return immediately, so that it can always return a valid dict. So you mean after the print(), it immediately returns? If that's the case, it would be my misunderstanding of exception handling.

Comment: @marlon, no I was wrong. You're right. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam Would the finally block resolves the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This can occur when `data` is `'null'`.

   In that case the JSON is valid, but it represents `None`. And because `'input' in` cannot be applied to `None`, this leads to the first -- handled -- error: the return value remains `None`.

   Now the loop wants to execute, but `None` is not iterable, and so you get a second -- unhandled -- error.
2. A similar error can occur when `data` is `'{ "input": null }'`

   In that case the second call to `json.loads` will trigger the first -- handled -- exception, and the dictionary that is returned is `{ "input": None }`

   Now the loop will bump into the same problem as above.
3. You should also look at the case where the JSON is valid, but just doesn't have an "input" property. In that case no `except` block will execute, but the main code will still have an issue to iterate over the non-existing `input` key.

#### Solution

Depending on what exactly you want to happen in that case, you could add the following statement in each of the two `except` blocks, and in an `else` block for the `if`:

```
return {'input': []}
```

That way it doesn't matter that the first `json.loads` assigned a value to `json_dict`... you'll still ignore that when it doesn't pass validation, and just return the default dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

This *exact* error message happens when `data == 'null'`:

```
>>> json_dict = parse_input('null')
json_str is not a string: null argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
>>> type(json_dict)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

In this case:

1. `json.loads('null')` returns `None`, so that `json_dict is None`
2. `'input' in json_dict` attempts to iterate over `None`, but that's an error
3. *Python* (not the JSON library!) thus throws the `TypeError`
4. Your code handles it and runs `print(f'json_str is not a string: {json_str} {e}')`. However, the error happened *not* because `json_str` wasn't a string, since `'null'` *is* a (Python) string.
5. Finally, `json_dict['input']` attempts to index into the `None` value, which is an error as well.

---

Similar behavior can happen when `data == '{"input": "null"}'`:

```
>>> parse_input('{"input": "null"}')
{'input': None}
```

This is caused by this line: `json_dict['input'] = json.loads(json_dict['input'])`. It parses the string `"null"` as the Python value `None` which `for input in json_dict['input']` attempts to iterate over, but that's basically `for input in None`, which is an error.

---

Here's another example of input that causes the code to fail:

```
>>> parse_input('{}')
{}
```

This happens because in `json_dict = json.loads(json_str)`, you're overwriting `json_dict`, so that now it may no longer contain the `'input'` key. In my example, `json_dict` is empty.

Then your code checks `if 'input' in json_dict:`. No, an empty dictionary *doesn't* have the `'input'` key, so your code proceeds to treat `json_dict` as... valid??? Even though it still *doesn't* contain the `'input'` key?

In code:

```
json_dict = json.loads(json_str)
if 'input' in json_dict:
    json_dict['input'] = json.loads(json_dict['input'])
else:
    ...
    # What if `'input' not in json_dict`?
    # Then `json_dict` remains invalid
```

Comment: @trincot, thanks! My answer ended up too similar to yours, though. I first misread OP's error message (3rd section of answer), then reproduced only part of it (2nd section), then finally saw that the `null` in `null argument of type 'NoneType'...` is actually `json_str` (1st section). But the two answers combined ended up highlighting like 4 different edge-cases in OP's code? That's the power of Stack Overflow!